# RegEx for exactly two or three words

Tags: javascript, html, regex, unicode, words

Could someone help me out with this?

At first I was trying to figure out how to simply check for input containing one or two words, and I was able to find that that would be with `\w* ?\w+` and for containing exactly two words would be with `\w+ \w+` And I got to something like this (which is not working):

`/^$|^([a-zA-ZčČćĆđĐšŠžŽ -])\w+ \w+$/`

What I've since figured out is that it should contain not one or two, but two or three words. And since I was unable to figure out the RegEx for two words to start with, I had to ask for help here.

Like I said, I need it to allow entering only **two or three** words with no numbers and with the addition of these letters **čČćĆđĐšŠžŽ** and a **-**

Also I need it to ignore a blank input, that's why `^$|` is there.

I am really, really new at this, so any help would be appreciated.

EXAMPLES:

- Marko Marković
- John Smith
- Mary-Jane Austin
- John III Johnson

Comment: Can you give some examples??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your new definition of "word" character to all the `\w`. This is for exactly 2 words, with exactly 1 space in between:

```
/^$|^[a-zA-ZčČćĆđĐšŠžŽ-]+ [a-zA-ZčČćĆđĐšŠžŽ-]+$/
```

For exactly 2 or 3 words:

```
/^$|^[a-zA-ZčČćĆđĐšŠžŽ-]+ [a-zA-ZčČćĆđĐšŠžŽ-]+( [a-zA-ZčČćĆđĐšŠžŽ-]+)?$/
```

Note that I have removed the space in your character class, since it shouldn't be considered part of a "word", or your "word" count will mess up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Unicode` regex to filter it out.

```
[\p{L}\s-]+
```

\p{L} : This will match any unicode alphabet from any language. 
\s    : Space character. 
-     : Dash ( - ).

You can see how it [matches here](https://regex101.com/r/xD8iM5/1).

For more about unicode regex you can [refer this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: It's a nice idea, but javascript doesn't have this.